# Replace Base XAML element with Templated element

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is some XAML source that I've simplified as much as possible

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="dTemplate" x:Key="DTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="templateGrid" Background="Orange" >
                <TextBox x:Name ="templateBox" Background="transparent" BorderThickness="0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="Text with the template.  Text with the template.  Text with the template.  ">
                </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="pageGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="elementGrid" Grid.Row="0" Background="Orange" >
        <TextBox x:Name="elementBox" Background="transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="Text without the template.  Text without the template.  Text without the template.  ">
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="elementControl" Grid.Row="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DTemplate}">
    </ContentControl>
    <Grid x:Name="elementGrid2" Grid.Row="2" Background="Orange">
        <ContentControl x:Name="elementControl2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DTemplate}">
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The pageGrid has three rows, just to illustrate the issue.

The first row of pageGrid is another Grid, elementGrid, which simply contains a TextBox; the purpose of elementGrid is to center the text within the row and fill with a background color.  Everything works the way it should.

But now I would like to use a template rather than the raw control, for the obvious reasons.  So I create a template that exactly corresponds to my raw control; that's dTemplate.  And then I instantiate that template using a ContentControl; I place that on the second row of pageGrid.

However, it doesn't work the same way - instead of a nice filled row, I get a band of orange in the center of the row.  And to get it to center, I have to put an explicit VerticalAlignment="Center" into the ContentControl, which I would not have thought should be necessary if the DataTemplate is correctly set up.

Now I can fix it, but in a way that seems to me to be an ugly kludge; I embed the ContentControl inside yet-another-Grid, keeping the VerticalAlignment=Center, and force the background color orange.  That solution is shown as the third row of pageGrid.

So, my question is: how can I fix DTemplate, so that the second row of pageGrid looks like the first, where elementControl is simply

```
<ContentControl x:Name="elementControl" Grid.Row="1"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DTemplate}">
</ContentControl>
```

Or am I simply approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: I think you should access it by Name not by Key DTemplate should be dTemplate

Comment: Hi @MohamedHamza.  I don't think so, unless I don't understand you.  StaticResource dTemplate is an error